# Howto add default parameters to component in the form.io editor

Tags: formio

I would like to add a default file location to the file upload control so that when someone drops a new file upload control onto their form, the values are already populated.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I was able to add the file component to a custom section in the editor, and specify default storage and file location at that point... i.e.

```
var builder = Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}, {
            builder: {
                custom: {
                  title: 'Extra',
                  weight: 20,
                  components: {
                    file: {
                      title: 'file',
                      key: 'file',
                      icon: 'file',
                      schema: {
                        label: 'Upload',
                        type: 'file',
                        key: 'file',
                        input: true,
                        storage: 'url',
                        url: 'https:yourfilelocation'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            })
```

Comment: If the answer you posted works for you, please mark it as such. That will help everyone landing here understand that it solves the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that everything that inside "schema" is not applied. But if i create for textfield or email component i was able to change label(for ex.)
This is working

```
  phoneNumber: {
      title: 'Mobile Phone',
      key: 'mobilePhone',
      icon: 'phone-square',
      schema: {
        label: 'Mobile Phoneff',
        type: 'phoneNumber',
        key: 'mobilePhone',
        tooltip:'debil',
        input: true
      }
    },
```

this is not

```
  file: {
      title: 'file',
      key: 'file',
      icon: 'file',
      schema: {
        label: 'IKBS',
        type: 'file',
        key: 'file',
        input: true,
        storage: 'url',
        tooltip:'debil',
        url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176446/howto-add-default-parameters-to-component-in-the-form-io-editor'
      }
    }
```